# Suppress GraphQL: Syntax Error in VS Code when using template string

Tags: graphql, syntax-error, apollo

> FYI: There are a ton of other posts concerning GraphQL Syntax Error in VS Code. I read many of them, but did not find anything relevant to this. My apologies if I missed it in the similar questions.

Environment:

- VS Code v.1.51.1
- Windows 10 x64 19041
- https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-tooling v.1.17.0
- React Typescript Application

I have a component that uses the useQuery hook. The query is retrieved from another query and comes in via a variable typed as `string` In order for the useQuery to correctly use the graphql query, it has first has to be made into a DocumentNode for which I use gql from graphql-tag npm package. The resulting code snippet looks like:

```js
...
const PREPARED_QUERY = useMemo(() => gql`${query}`, [query])
const data = useQuery(PREPARED_QUERY, queryOptions)
...
```

This is working code, but the Apollo GraphQL extension throws a warning on this line:

`Syntax Error: Unexpected <EOF>.GraphQL: Syntax`

I understand this is because it is checking the query string to ensure that it is properly formatted and it does not understand the template string "hack".

Questions:

1. Can this be silences with some form of ignore comment?
2. If not, Is there any way to form this to make this template string pass the syntax check?

Comment: Is it not a better practice to do : `const x = gql\`your actual query\`` and use the variable `x` elsewhere, is it not possible in your scenario? Usually you're supposed to write one gql query and then affect it only using the `variables` object. A dynamic sort of query probably wouldn't work so well.

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar the query is stored in a database and comes in through another query. It is an unusual setup I will admit. The use case is for allowing admins to create these queries to build data filters dynamically in the UI rather than hard code all of the options in the UI source code.

Comment: From what I have experienced so far, as long as each query has it's unique name then Apollo Client will play nice. I make sure that the dynamic queries have unique names.

Comment: I don't believe it has something to do with your using variable interpolation insead of hardcoded query text. However, I suspect the actual content of your `query` variable is not a valid graphql query - and Apollo complains about that

Comment: @amakhrov Apollo complains about this error in the IDE without the application even running. The variable at rest does not contain anything because the variable is filled from a separate query transaction that pulls a valid query string from the database. At rest in the IDE the variable is indeed empty, but it will never hit this point without a valid string query. What I need is to remove the ugly red dot on this file though.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. Looks like a known issue with the vscode extension - without a known solution :) https://github.com/graphql/vscode-graphql/issues/137 . Since `gql` is just a function, you might want to call it directly, and perhaps the extension won't recognize it: `gql( [ [ query ] ] )` (note nested array)

Comment: @amakhrov that is actually a good answer. In my current situation I was able to put it in the form of `gql(query)` and it bypassed the error and it still works. I didn't need to nested array syntax, not sure why that would be needed. FYI I am using gql from graphql-tag package which has the type: `gql(literals: string | readonly string[], ...placeholders: any[]): DocumentNode`

Comment: read docs: "A more advanced form of template literals are tagged templates."

Comment: reposted the comment above as an answer to increase visibility - also added explanation on how template tags work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a known issue with the vscode extension - without a known solution :) https://github.com/graphql/vscode-graphql/issues/137 .

#### Workaround

Since `gql` is just a function, you can call it directly, so that the extension won't try to parse it and stop complaining.

```
gql(query)
```

#### Explanation on why it works

If we take a look at [tagged templates docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates), we'll see that it's a regular function that takes the array of static string pieces as the first argument, and interpolated expressions as the remaining arguments.
So when we do

```
gql`some content`
```

it translates to the following function call:

```
gql(["some content"]) // a single argument, because there is no interpolations here
```

Also this `gql` function has special code inside that allows to pass a plain string as the first arg (probably to support old JS where no template tags existed)